Change Duration Column from Text Type to Number/Time Data Type
I am using the below formula to calculate the duration in HH:MM:SS formula.
However, I am unable to update this new column to Number/Time data type as the colons ":" are necessary in the Text type, but would not be necessary if the type was Time.
I need to sum this result and as you are aware im sure, the text column types does not allow this.
Adjusted Duration HHMMSS = 
VAR _hrs = QUOTIENT ( Total[Average Duration Adjusted] , 60 )
VAR _mins = INT (Total[Average Duration Adjusted] - _hrs * 60 )
VAR _sec = MOD ( Total[Average Duration Adjusted] , 1.0 ) * 60
RETURN
FORMAT(_hrs,"00")&":"&FORMAT(_mins,"00")&":"&FORMAT(_sec,"00")

Source column :

Adjusted duration :

Please help!
Should I include a TIMEVALUE line in my formula?
Thank you!!
I attempted to update the column type to whole numbers and removing the colons but this does not work as expected.
I would expect this column to be a time column so it can be summed not "first" or counted.

Instead of formatting the result as HH:MM:SS, try to calculate the total duration in seconds:
Adjusted Duration Total Seconds = 
VAR _hrs = QUOTIENT(Total[Average Duration Adjusted], 60)
VAR _mins = INT(Total[Average Duration Adjusted] - _hrs * 60)
VAR _sec = MOD(Total[Average Duration Adjusted], 1.0) * 60
RETURN
_hrs * 3600 + _mins * 60 + _sec

Then you can convert it back to time format :
Adjusted Duration HHMMSS = 
TIME(
    QUOTIENT([Adjusted Duration Total Seconds], 3600), 
    MOD(QUOTIENT([Adjusted Duration Total Seconds], 60), 60), 
    MOD([Adjusted Duration Total Seconds], 60)
)



Update :
You can use the CC Adjusted Duration Total Seconds to create your measure :
Total Adjusted Duration in Seconds = SUM('Total'[Adjusted Duration Total Seconds])

and another measure to convert the summed seconds back into  HH:MM:SS format:
Total Adjusted Duration HHMMSS = 
VAR _TotalSeconds = [Total Adjusted Duration in Seconds]
VAR _hrs = QUOTIENT(_TotalSeconds, 3600)
VAR _mins = QUOTIENT(MOD(_TotalSeconds, 3600), 60)
VAR _secs = MOD(_TotalSeconds, 60)
RETURN
FORMAT(_hrs, "00") & ":" & FORMAT(_mins, "00") & ":" & FORMAT(_secs, "00")

